DIY linseed oil paint ratios
I'm making my own white linseed oil paint to paint my house (which is in NJ, so cold winters, hot summers.)
Does anyone know the proper amounts for the latter three ingredients? Am I missing any ingredients?
Thanks!!
Linseed oil - 1 gallon
Titanium (pigment) - 500g
Zinc Sulfate (for faster drying) - ?
Zinc Oxide (anti-mold) - ?
Turpentine (for thinning) - ?

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. You've clearly done some research on this, it's important that you list some or all of the references you looked at and give us an idea why they didn't give you what you wanted/needed. Is there a specific reason you didn't just go with one of the formulas online? As in, is there something specific you feel one or all of them lack that someone can speak to?

If you're looking for a Goldilocks recipe I'm afraid you're going to be disappointed as there isn't one. So, proper amounts? There aren't any. Missing ingredients? Depends who you ask. Different people have different opinions on what makes the best paint formula — based largely on personal opinions they've picked up from wherever — but much more important are the qualities of the linseed oil (this can vary far more than you might expect) and the mixing methodology play a massive part in how the paint comes together and subsequently works (application) and performs (holds up over time).

While this is a somewhat interesting notion, I’m considering a VTC because it’s so opinion driven. Maybe somebody has something canonical up their sleeve. (And to the OP: given the cost of labor, I sincerely hope you get this right the first time if you insist on going down this path.)

@AloysiusDefenestrate, not just the cost of labour, look at what a gallon of good linseed oil costs.... cos presumably if you're going this route you're using good linseed oil, not BLO from the hardware store. (And for giggles, there's this LOL)
